# Why is my string losing its value?

Tags: c++, string, compare

For some reason, the value of my toCheck variable is getting erased and I have no idea why.  Any suggestions?

```
bool
check(string toCheck){
    printf("toCheck: %s\n", toCheck.c_str());
    ifstream list;
    list.open("list.txt");
    string temp;
    while(list){
        getline(list,temp);
        printf("toCheck: '%s' temp: '%s'\n",toCheck.c_str(), temp.c_str());
        if(temp == toCheck){
            printf("Username exists\n");
            return false;
        }
    }
    printf("returning true\n");
    return true;
}
```

Here's what it is being passed: TestTrevor

And here's the output:

> ```
> toCheck: TestTrevor  
> toCheck: '' temp: 'Trevor'  
> toCheck: '' temp: ''  
>
> Username exists
> ```

Comment: What are the contents of list.txt?

Comment: You must be channeling some dark magic via "list.txt".

Comment: removing list.txt, and just subbing in some dummyvalues for temp, your code works expected on my MacbookPro.

Comment: Works fine for me using g++ egcs-2.91.57. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Works fine with MSVC 11 dev preview, you have an evil fairy lurking in your list.txt.

Comment: @Scarlet: or perhaps nasal demons? Is there any chance of undefined behaviour here? I don't think so, but then it's way past my bedtime.

Comment: well, we're assuming he's using `std::string` so maybe he wrote his own string class, and c_str() is causing the headache :P

Comment: haha, no, using std::string and the contents are:
Trevor

Comment: Is this your exact code, or is it a little bit different from yours?

Comment: I'm honestly intrigued by this. You may have ripped the time-space continuum apart and you're virtually losing the bytes into an alternate dimension. That's the only solution i've managed to come up with so far.

Comment: Exact code.  If it means anything, I'm on school computers that have, in the past, caused undefined behavior when dealing with std::strings.  On solaris, again, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Could you try using C++ streams (`cout`) instead of `printf`?

Comment: Can you debug the code step by step?

Comment: This works fine for me on GCC 4.6.2/windows with all of "TestTrevor", "TestTrevor\n" and "abc\nTestTrevor" in my text file.

Comment: Your computers caused UB when dealing with std::strings ? Are you in Hogwarts ? Or possibly a school with many chemical labs around ? Producing who knows what ? Bit-eating pigmys ?

Comment: It's really hard to debug (which is why I'm using printf) because I'm forking and using processes (this is a server for a VoIP project I'm working on) and the gdb wasn't working when I tried to follow the child process

Comment: Does empty line exist in actual output? It should not...

Comment: If you say that the computers "are known to cause UB with std::string", is there ANY chance that the string has been redefined with the very same "std::" namespace ?

Comment: NEW INFO: if I comment out the 'getLine(list,temp);' then it doesn't erase toCheck, any thoughts?

Comment: @Trevor Could you please try to do the following: create a temp string before printf -> std::string myTemp = toCheck; and then just c_str() it in printf().

Comment: I think it could be possible in case that the _string_ class is implemented using a singleton... which is obviously not true

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth I added a temp and set it equal to toCheck and both of them were cleared/erased (whatever is happening)

Comment: I'm starting to believe that perhaps your standard library implementation might be bugged.

Comment: @Trevor Both of them were erased ? Are you absolutely positive you have #include <string> and using std::string (watch out for overlapping namespaces and such stuffs ...) ?

Comment: I have no idea, I have no control over the version of anything on these computers (like I said, school computers)

Comment: using namespace std;
 
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <sys/wait.h>
 #include <sys/socket.h>
 #include <netinet/in.h>
 #include <netdb.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <time.h>
 #include <string>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <signal.h>

Comment: Try allocating a tempstring on the heap and assign one of the strings you print to it. Tell me whether it erases the contents of that one as well.

Comment: Guys, seriosuly seriously, we need to see the contents of the list.txt. This could very easily be a printf formatting bug (i.e. accidental passing of extra arguments pushing the c_str's off the end)

Comment: @OrgnlDave Really? `printf` parses the contents of a string passed with `%s`?

Comment: How does the data space for 'string temp' become allocated to store the output from getLine?  Does ifstream.getline have an overload for 'string' strings?

Answer (score 4):

From your comments:

> It's really hard to debug (which is why I'm using `printf`) because **I'm forking** and using processes (this is a server for a VoIP project I'm working on) and the gdb wasn't working when I tried to follow the child process.

Emphasis mine.

I would not be surprised if the memory dynamically allocated for `toCheck` never really made it into the forked process, or made it but was somehow discarded / overwritten.

> NEW INFO: if I comment out the `getLine(list, temp);` then it doesn't erase `toCheck`, any thoughts?

This is the very first time in your program that the `std::allocator` is required to actually allocate memory.

---

The STL has never been developped with forking in mind, so it is perfectly possible than it simply *does not work* in this usecase.

You could check what's going on with a debugger. See at which address the memory for `toCheck` is allocated and what happens when memory is allocated for `temp`, but it's deep diving.

Since it seems you have issues with gdb, you can try dumping the addresses first (`printf("%x", &toCheck[0]);`).